# What exceptions does boost::process::child throw?

Tags: c++, boost-process

In the process [tutorial](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_81_0/doc/html/boost_process/tutorial.html#boost_process.tutorial.error_handling), it states

> The default behaviour of all functions is to throw an `std::system_error` on failure.

However, the example given is using `boost::process::system`. Do `boost::process::child` functions throw a `std::system_error` the way `boost::system` functions do? Where could I find this information in future for other classes? It's not part of the [class documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_81_0/doc/html/boost/process/child.html)

Comment: Since capturing should be by reference almost always, maybe they mean that they throw a `system_error` in the sense that you should capture by `system_error&`. And `process_error` (derived from it) is just an implementation detail.

Answer (score 2):

Tutorial indeed states `std::system_error` while reference docs state this:

```cpp
namespace boost {
  namespace process {
    struct process_error;
  }
}
```

Code inspection is the ultimate answer (boost/process/exception.hpp):

```cpp
namespace boost
{
namespace process
{
///The exception usually thrown by boost.process.
/** It merely inherits [std::system_error](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/system_error)
 * but can then be distinguished in the catch-block from other system errors.
 *
 */
struct process_error : std::system_error
{
    using std::system_error::system_error;
};

}
}
```

If a function marked `noexcept` throws, `std::terminate` is called; effectively this allows to simplify the reasoning about them as generally non-throwing ones.
Otherwise, i.e. without `noexcept` or with `noexcept(false)`, a function can throw anything. In the end it is up to the programmer to believe the specification or not.

Comment: A function marked `noexcept` can `throw` just fine. It's just that doing so will result in `std::terminate` being invoked.

Comment: @JesperJuhl right, I might have taken too big a shortcut when explaining it, edited.